# Get integer from javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a strings with the values like:

`share__43
share__153
share
share_section`

How do I get the integer values like 43 or 153?

Comment: You have **a** string or you have multiple strings? Is it one string with space separated parts or four separate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example, currently using a single string

```
var regex = /\d+/;
var str = "share__43";
alert (str.match(regex ));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3gtj/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var regex = new RegExp(/([0-9]+)/g);
var test = "share__43 share__153 share share_section";

var match = regex.exec(test);
alert('Found: ' + match[1]);
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/4E2nu/)

Comment: too long for a simple action

Comment: @Steve What does that even mean? What are you trying to do exactly?